# Are there cases where a typedef is absolutely necessary?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, typedef, coercion, safe-bool-idiom

Consider the following excerpt from the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html):

```
typedef void (Testable::*bool_type)() const;
operator bool_type() const;
```

Is it possible to declare the conversion function without the typedef? The following does not compile:

```
operator (void (Testable::*)() const)() const;
```

Comment: Why would you declare the function without the typedef?

Comment: Is conversion to safe bool absolutely necessary?

Comment: @Tad: It seems useful in my particular case (an `optional<T>` class template).

Comment: @Tad: I myself use the safe bool idiom fairly often, @Fred: I would note that the `typedef` helps producing more readable code/errors.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#395

Comment: Don't treat me so seriously. It was a failed attempt towards a pundit badge :-)

Comment: @Johannes: But `template <typename T> using id = T;` isn't in the standard library, right? :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, I just remembered the `identity` meta-function. It is possible to write

```
operator typename identity<void (Testable::*)() const>::type() const;
```

with the following definition of `identity`:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

You could argue that `identity` still uses a `typedef`, but this solution is "good" enough for me.

Comment: I was going to answer right this... `identity` is a nice way of getting around parsing problems.

Comment: @David: Sadly, `identity` is not part of standard C++0x. In this case, we could use `std::decay`, though...

Comment: That's a better version of what I was going for!

Answer (score 3):

One case (unrelated to your question) where a `typedef` is required is when using the

`va_arg()` macro.  Quoting the C99 standard (7.15.1.1):

> type* va_arg(va_list ap, *type*);

...

> The parameter *type* shall be a
>   type name specified such that the type of a pointer to an object that
>   has the specified type can be obtained simply by postfixing a * to
>   *type*

Comment: there's another such case, namely call of pseudo-destructor

Comment: I.e. `p->~unsigned char()` isn't allowed ( for those who don't know what a pseudo-destructor is or why you'd need a typedef there).

Answer (score 3):

Answering the "Are there cases where a typedef is absolutely necessary?" from the question title, here is one example of where a typedef is needed:

```
f(unsigned char());   // compiler error!
typedef unsigned char Byte;
f(Byte());            // fine!
```

See the results here: http://ideone.com/JPUra

Comment: Compiler war again! GCC fails, VC succeeds.

Comment: How about `f(identity<unsigned char>::type())`? ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow that looks like it'll work, although technically `type` is a typedef. :P

Answer (score 2):

My analysis says that it is not possible without using `typedef`. The compiler sees `(` as the first token and assumes you are overloading `() operator`, which shouldn't have any arguments (The arguments would come in next set of parenthesis). Putting any set of extra parenthesis wouldn't help either - but would actually confuse the compiler and hence set of more errors.

Most of the STL code is on top of `typedef`initions, and we should/must use them!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the grammar demands using a typedef in your case. A *conversion-function-id* must be of the form **operator** *conversion-type-id*. The *conversion-type-id* cannot contain parentheses. So you must use typedef when converting to a pointer-to-function type, or to a pointer-to-member-function type.

Comment: "The conversion-type-id cannot contain parentheses." Where do you get that from?

Comment: @TonyK: from the grammar. It is basically a maybe const/volatile primitive type or a qualified id (type-specifier-seq), followed by zero or more pointer-operators (conversion-declarator-opt).

Comment: @n: I found a way: `template <int T> class C { } ;
class S { operator C<(99)>*() { return 0 ; } } ;`

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can do it like this (gcc 4.5.2):

```
operator decltype((void (Testable::*)() const)(0))() const ;
```

I'm not saying it's pretty...

Comment: Have you tried with `decltype( &Testable::foo )` where `foo` is a member method with the appropriate signature?

Answer (score 1):

A `typedef` is not a macro your second example is not equivalent to the first. In the first case your `typedef` is defining a functor then using that type in a cast operator of the functor type. In the second the operator is using bad syntax as there is no operator specified because there is no type. I'm not sure how to write it but there is a way usually.

<strike>Typedefs aren't really necessary except for making human readable code in TMP and even then it depends on what kind of human you are.</strike>

Since I can't come up with the alternative syntax maybe typedefs are necessary in some cases. I just thought of another one possibly. Say you had a template with specializations which contained a static method with a return type like below:

```
template <typename T>
struct WhateverHandler
{
   typedef T rType;
   static rType Whatever() { return rType(); }
};

template <>
struct WhateverHandler<std::string>
{
   typedef std::string rType;
   static rType Whatever() { return rType(); }
};
```

I think in this case also you would need the typedef in order to call the static method regardless of specialization as otherwise the method could confuse the compiler because the return types would differ but it wouldn't be a proper overload.

```
template <typename T>
struct WhateverUser
{
   typename WhateverHandler<T>::rType DoWhatever()
   {
       return WhateverHandler<T>::template Whatever();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this issue, with clang++:

```
foo.cpp:17:8: error: must use a typedef to declare a conversion to 'void (*(int))()'
```

and there's a C++11 STL template which covers the identity<T> functionality:

```
#include <type_traits>
…
struct foo {
     void bar( ) const { }
     operator std::common_type<void(foo::*)( )const>::type( ) { return &foo::bar; }
};
```