# Template conversion operator returing reference to array

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading this question and some other stuff : [Are there cases where a typedef is absolutely necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998750/are-there-cases-where-a-typedef-is-absolutely-necessary)?

I wrote this code :

```
const int arrayOfInt[10] = {0};

template<typename T, int N> using X = const T (&)[N];

struct foo
{
    template<typename T, int N> operator  X<int,10> () { return arrayOfInt;  }
};

void bar(const int (&) [10]) {}

int main()
{
    bar(foo());
    return 0;
}
```

`using` feature of c++11 is not working for me , also I'm unable to think how to `typedef` the return type in this case too since my class `foo` is not template itself. I need to see solution using `using` keyword and `typedef` both . Thanks a lot awesome peoples of SO :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `operator X<T, N>`?

Comment: Please always when you say that something is not working, post the actual compiler error message.

Comment: @KerrekSB Love ya :) , thanks for helping us noobs :)

Comment: @KerrekSB "error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const int (&)[10]' from expression of type 'foo' "

Comment: Hm, maybe `operator const X<T, N>&`? You cannot have prvalues of array type in C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB maybe template conversion operator is bad idea? . The program just won't work!

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do. Sometimes templated conversion operators can enable a huge amount of magic.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks, some examples of that magic? :)

Comment: E.g. a proxy object from which you can construct arbitrary ranges: `template <typename T> operator T() const { return T(internal_begin(), internal_end()); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename T, int N> operator  X<int,10> () { return arrayOfInt;  }
```

template arguments T and N are never used and hence shall never be deduced.

Fixed **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b185fbda14c4eaf1)</kbd>**

```
const int arrayOfInt[10]{0};

template<typename T, int N> using X = T const (&)[N];

struct foo {
    template<typename T, int N> operator  X<T,N> () const { return arrayOfInt;  }
};

void bar(const int (&) [10]) {}

int main()
{
    foo f;
    X<int, 10> v = f;
    bar(foo());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but can you please explain in my code`template<typename T, int N> operator  X<int,10> () { return arrayOfInt;  }` -> `X<int,10>` doesn't changes the semantics of code from your corrected code, yet it produces error. Thanks

Comment: What part of it do you replace? I don't see the difference. The problem is there is no way to _explicitly_ specify the arguments for `T` and `N` (afaik).

Comment: Awesome, now I realize my puny mistake. Thanks a lot sir :)

Comment: Though when I try to call conversion function template explicitly I get baffling error -> `foo().operator X<int,10><int,10>()` , so my last question, is it even possible to call conversion function template explicitly ?

Comment: Yes, [it's impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039828/template-conversion-operator-returing-reference-to-array/34989172#comment57707371_34989172). However if you have to (a) you have other problems :) (b) it's easily fixed (by creating the non-operator template member and implementing one in terms of the other)

Answer (score 2):

Since `X` is an alias template you need to provide the template arguments explicitly; they won't be captured from the surrounding scope:

```
struct foo
{
    template<typename T, int N> 
    operator X<T,N>() { return arrayOfInt; }
    //        ^^^^^
};
```

You can't do this with a `typedef` as there's no such thing as a typedef template.

Comment: but I still get error "error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const int (&)[10]' from expression of type 'foo' "